# Can't launch protractor tests on saucelabs from teamcity

Tags: selenium, teamcity, protractor, saucelabs

I am trying to run my automated tests using protractor from teamcity on saucelabs.

If i use the exact same config and capabilities from my local machine, the tests run on saucelabs vm perfectly.

If I try launching them from teamcity, the vm are not provisioned and my tests failed with either `UnknownError: null` or `Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at`

I've tried changing the host to ondemand.saucelabs.com:80 and the same errors happened.

I've tried with and without sauce connect and same errors.

I've tried specifying the selenium version to 2.48.0 and the same errors happened.

I'm out of idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally managed to launch my tests on Sauce from teamcity.

The issue was neither from teamcity nor sauce.

In fact my rake task launching the tests was also trying to launch webdriver and selenium servers which is done by saucelabs.
Somehow it messed up everything.

Now that I have rewrote the tasks to only launch protractor `<specfile>` it works like a charm!